# How to output every combination of values in 2 columns, in groups? - SQL

Tags: sql, join, group-by, amazon-redshift, cross-join

I have a table where I want every parent to be mapped to every child within each group.

Input:

```
group_id     parent     child
1            A          E
1            B    
2            C          F
2            D
2            E          G      
3            X
3            Y
```

Output:

```
group_id     parent     child
1            A          E
1            B          E
2            C          F
2            D          F
2            E          F      
2            C          G
2            D          G
2            E          G
```

So within each group, I want every value in `parent` to map to every value in `child`. If there are no values in `child` for a group, I want that group completely omitted (as shown where `group_id` = 3)

I was originally thinking of using `GROUP BY 1, 2` and aggregating by something like `MAX(child)`, but then I came across edge cases in my data where there may be >1 child. I also tried using `CROSS JOIN` but I'm struggling with getting my desired output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output do you want to have for 2 children in a group?

Comment: This is the group 2 case in my example, where F and G are both children in a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer, I don't use Redshift so there may be better options. However, a CROSS JOIN should work. Just grab the DISTINCT parent values for all groups. Then do the same for the child values, and JOIN the two results together

```
SELECT  p.group_id, p.parent, c.child
FROM   ( 
           SELECT group_id, parent
           FROM   YourTable
           GROUP BY group_id, parent
       ) 
       p CROSS JOIN 
       (
           SELECT group_id, child
           FROM   YourTable
           WHERE  child IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY group_id, child       
       )
       c 
WHERE  p.group_id = c.group_id
ORDER BY p.group_id, c.child, p.parent
```

**Results:**

| group_id | parent | child |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | E |
| 1 | B | E |
| 2 | C | F |
| 2 | D | F |
| 2 | E | F |
| 2 | C | G |
| 2 | D | G |
| 2 | E | G |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=27d62edf17e8f3533d1e7eb29fafa6be)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it exploiting a variable. The variable will be set to the value of `child` if its value is not null, otherwise it will copy over the value contained in the variable

```
SET @child := "";
SELECT 
    group_id,
    parent,
    IF(child IS NULL, @child, @child := child) AS child
FROM 
    tab
```

Here's a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5KnoFogV19jc4nWa8rrzVx/0.

Does it work for you?

Comment: I don't think Redshift has the concept of variables unfortunately :\